# Using (Nested Loop) .find to grab identical values seperate sheets VBA EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which loops through two different worksheets and compares column A to column A checking if the same value is on the other sheet. If it is then the row is colored in green.

```
Dim compareRange As Range
Dim toCompare As Range
Dim rFound As Range
Dim cel As Range

Set compareRange = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1:A" & Lastrow3)
Set toCompare = Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A1:A" & Lastrow4)
Set rFound = Nothing

For Each cel In toCompare
Set rFound = compareRange.Find(cel)
If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
    cel.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 5296274
    Set rFound = Nothing
End If
Next cel
```

Now that I have the cell with the row how do I grab the cells from the same row but on different column? because now I want to check if column L from sheet2 matches column L from sheet3. If it doesn't I want to be grab that value from sheet2 and put it in a new row below on in the same column L. Any guidance or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Define grab?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Are you already getting your row colorization?

Comment: Look into the Range.Offset() Property, if you offset by a certain integer you can increment it as part of your loop if necessary.

Comment: I'm trying to grab the value of whatever is in column L on sheet2 on the same row that I found the cel matching with A. L values are OPEN or CLOSED. Lets say row A in sheet2 and row A in sheet3 matched on the fifth loop and both had values 123 and 123. Now I want to stay in the same row and grab whatever is in Column F sheet2 and compare with Column F sheet3.

Comment: Store your value into a variable?  Something like `var = cel("L" & cel).Value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help demostrate how to do what youre after

```
Private Sub compAre()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim sht1 As Range
    Dim rcell As Range

    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A3")

    For Each rcell In sht1.Cells
        If rcell.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("L" & rcell.Row).Value Then
            sht1.Rows.Interior.Color = vbBlue
        End If
    Next rcell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see how this is grabbing from a different column is A matches? Are you saying ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F" & rcell.Row).Value Then?

Comment: @AngatvirSanghera Edited to show you how to grad L :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that covers most of what you describe, coloring the cells that match and putting those into column L of the 3rd sheet. I didn't understand the remainder of the question after that, but this should give you a good start. The animation starts by showing the contents of sheets 1,2,3 and then shows those sheets again after running the macro.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, num As Integer
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range, cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range
Set sh1 = Worksheets("1")
Set sh2 = Worksheets("2")
Set sh3 = Worksheets("3")
Set r1 = Range(sh1.Range("A1"), sh1.Range("A1").End(xlDown))
Set r2 = Range(sh2.Range("A1"), sh2.Range("A1").End(xlDown))
Set r3 = sh3.Range("L1")
For Each cell1 In r1
  For Each cell2 In r2
    If cell1 = cell2 Then
      cell1.Interior.Color = vbGreen
      cell2.Interior.Color = vbGreen
      r3 = cell1.Value
      Set r3 = r3.Offset(1, 0)
      num = num + 1
    End If
  Next
Next
MsgBox (num & " were found to match")
End Sub
```

[image]